# How to install VMWare Tools in Linux?

Tags: linux, terminal, vmware

I'm using VMWare and a Linux Mint guest OS.

How can I install the VMWare Tools? The file is called vmware-install.pl

I've tried running this in the terminal, but it doesn't work.

> sudo vmware-install.pl

I can't seem to remember what command I had to use. Thanks!

Comment: Turns out I needed: sudo ./vmware-install.pl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future reference, the `.pl` extension is generally used for Perl scripts. Ensure the file is executable (`chmod +x vmware-install.pl`) then run `./vmware-install.pl` or `sudo vmware-install.pl` if you are not in a privileged shell. If there is a properly written she-bang line it will run the script. If not, try `sudo perl vmware-install.pl`.

Comment: it gives me this error: bash: ./vmware-install.pl /usr/bin/perl: bad interpreter: no such file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
sudo perl vmware-install.pl
```

The .pl is a Perl file, might also need to make sure Perl and the other dependencies listed in the docs are installed too.